# How to change / override the default color for disabled fields in Vuetify js?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

By default vuetify applies light grey shade for disabled textfields/items. How i can override this color to the color i want?

currently i am using  disabled selector `:disabled {   color: #000000 !important; }`  which only helps with changing the color of textfields text color, i also have Dropdown and checkboxes in my form. is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could target

checkbox with `.input-group--disabled.checkbox .input-group__input`

and dropdown with `.input-group--disabled.input-group--select label`

```
.input-group--disabled.checkbox .input-group__input {
    color: #000 !important;
}

.input-group--disabled.input-group--select label {
    color: #000 !important;
}
```

---

Afaics most classes have `--disabled` suffix, so perhaps this could work for you (but I didn't test):

```
[class$="--disabled"],
[class*="--disabled "] * {
    color: #000 !important; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you @traxo for helping me second time... please help me with more upcoming questions :P

Comment: How come I see style changes in dev, but not in production version?

Answer (score 9):

I have been trying this with text fields to override class and it's not working, but there is a handy prop called 'readonly' for all the form input elements. Use 'readonly' instead of 'disabled'.

```
<v-textarea placeholder="Notes" :readonly="true"></v-textarea>
<v-select :items="['Mango', 'Apple']" label="Filled style" :readonly="true"></v-select>
```

Comment: Readonly doesen't prevent click event so it's not of much use in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Select all descendants and apply the color.

```
.input-group__input *
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87) !important
```